# Inverse of a continuos function

Tags: continuity, inverse-function

If $f:I\subseteq \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is injective and everywhere continuous in its domain then $f^{-1}$ is also continuous everywhere. **Here  $I$ cannot be discrete set and $f$ is single variable function** The above statement is always correct or not? I thought it is always correct. Am I correct or not?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli The question in your link got its shape after it was edited. This happened quite some time after answers were given allready. I recommended the OP to roll back edit (so that answers on the original question stayed in correct correspondence) and to ask it as a new question. He did ask a new question (this one), but did not roll back the edit of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I=(0,1]\cup(2,3]$ and consider
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in(0,1] \\ x-1 & x \in (2,3] \end{cases} $$

Your claim is true if $I$ is an *interval*, but "not discrete" is not enough.

Comment: Nice explanation